# $S$ and $T$ globally isomorphic semigroups, with $S$ (commutative and) cancellative, iff $S$ is isomorphic to $T$?

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

Denote by $\mathcal P(S)$ the semigroup obtained by equipping the non-empty subsets of a "ground semigroup" $S$ (written multiplicatively) with the operation of setwise multiplication induced by $S$:
$$
(X, Y) \mapsto XY := \{xy \colon x \in X, \, y \in Y\}.
$$
In the literature, $\mathcal P(S)$ is called the *power semigroup* (or *global*) of $S$. Two semigroups are then said to be *globally isomorphic* if their power semigroups are isomorphic.

**QUESTION.** Let $S$ and $T$ be semigroups and assume $S$ is cancellative and globally isomorphic to $T$. Is it known whether $S$ is necessarily isomorphic to $T$? And what about the case when $S$ is cancellative and commutative?

If any of the answers turns out to be yes, I would greatly appreciate a reference.

**Update (Feb 25, 2024).** On the 2nd page of [M. Gould, J.A. Iskra, and C. Tsinakis, *Globals of completely regular periodic semigroups*, Semigroup Forum 29 (1984), 365-374], one can read:

> Tamura [15] surveyed the recent papers and added to the list the class of all semilattice-indecomposable cancellative semigroups".

Here, 'the list' is the list of semigroups for which it was known by the time of Tamura's survey that two semigroups $S$ and $T$ in a certain class are globally isomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic; and [15] is [T. Tamura, *On the semigroups of subsets of semigroups*, Proc. 6th Symposium on Semigroups, Ritsumeikan Univ. (1982), 11-18]. Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of Tamura's paper.

In the meanwhile, I've arXived a [short note](https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.11475) where, as a special case of a more general result, a positive answer to the above question is provided for the class of cancellative *commutative* semigroups. The (cancellative) non-commutative case remains largely open.

Comment: Questions of this type (when global isomorphic semigroups are isomorphic) are studied in https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793557117500383 but I didn't check if your specific case is covered there. I would use Google scholar to check the citations (recursively).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I've already done that before asking here. Questions of this type (or closely related ones) are studied in a number of other papers (in J. Algebra, Isr. J. Math., Proc. AMS, etc.). The problem itself was formally posed by Tamura and Shafer in the late 1960s (if not even before by Schein).

Comment: Alright, then ignore my comment 